# How to maintain metadata when encoding WEBP or insert metadata to ready WEBP images?

Tags: command-line, metadata, exif, webp, xmp

I have `PNG` images with `EXIF`, `XMP` and `IPTC` metadata that I want to maintain, when I create `WEBP` images.

I am running a **Windows** computer. I have tried a few ways and I failed.
I know that `WEBP` doesn't support `IPTC` metadata, just `EXIF` and `XMP`, I would be fine if just `XMP` would be maintained/transferred to `WEBP`.

Original [WEBP encoder](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp) by Google has this option:

> -metadata **string**: A comma separated list of metadata to copy from the input to the output if present. Valid values: all, none, **exif**, **icc**,
> **xmp**. The default is none.

I've used such command line:

```
cwebp -metadata all image.png -o image.webp
```

However, such command line brings this warning, thus no metadata is maintained:

```
Warning: only ICC profile extraction is currently supported on this platform!
```

I've also tried another Google tool [WebpMux](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/webpmux). I've exported `EXIF` and `XMP` metadata blocks with [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) to `.exif` and `.xmp` files and ran such command lines:

```
webpmux -set exif image.exif image1.webp -o image2.webp
webpmux -set xmp image.xmp image1.webp -o image2.webp
```

Metadata wasn't inserted.

I then found [Exiv2](https://exiv2.org/index.html) tool, that says that it's capable of inserting image metadata into `WEBP` images.

I've tried this command:

```
exiv2 -ee- image.png | exiv2 -ie- image.webp
```

It copies just some of the `XMP` metadata, not all, for instance, image headline isn't copied, while description is.

I've also tried extracting metadata with [Exiv2](https://exiv2.org/index.html) to an `.exv` file and them inserting it into `WEBP` file via this command line:

```
exiv2 -ep image.webp
```

No luck.

I have also tried importing `EXIF` and `XMP` metadata files with [Exiv2](https://exiv2.org/index.html) - didn't work as well.

**QUESTIONS:**

Is there any working way to insert `EXIF` and/or `XMP` metadata to `WEBP` images?
Or maybe I've used the tools wrong? Share the proper command lines then please.

Comment: I've tried ffmpeg with animated and still webp images and also no luck.

Comment: Also no luck with exiftool (not supported)...

Comment: this online tool also doesn't seem to work: https://products.groupdocs.app/metadata/webp